# carousel slider showing extra space when viewed in small devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, device

[image]I have a carousel slider which works perfectly in large screens. But when the same is viewed in small devices, a extra space of gray background is added. The same can be viewed in (ctrl+shift+m) in firefox of this [SITE LINK](http://128.199.168.154/events) . When viewed in firebug, I have noticed that it might due to

```
element.style {
    height:345.6px
}
```

If I remove the height, it works perfectly. How to fix this ?

UPDATE: If no slider appears, please select change city to **Guwahati**

Comment: Try to use `@media` so you can modify the style in small screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need more information to help you. Are you using some kind of template? Do you have access to the the raw HTML or CSS? Please be more clear about how we can help.

Edit:
True this should be a comment. Sorry about that. Give the element a specific class and override the template CSS. Something like this:
HTML:

```
<section id="home" class="customHeightStyle home-section home-parallax home-fade bg-dark-30" data-background="" style="height: 480.24px; top: 0px; background-position: 82px 38px, 44px 31px, 22px 15px;">
```

CSS:

```
.customHeightStyle {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes I am using a template and have access to HTML/CSS files..

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer!

Comment: Thanks :) working nicely

Answer (score 0):

In html, add the same image as `background` for the parent `.item`. And use `background-size:cover;`

For small screen sizes, hide the image using `opacity` or `visibility`.

Increase the height of `.carousel`, `.carousel-inner` and `.item` to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have set height of the container element and then styled the image to be 100% in width.

The upper image is trying to preserve best aspect ratio. You need to set the height of containers properly and then try adding images as cover photos to individual sliders with `background-image and background-size` property.

Answer (score 0):

Remove youe section style height: 5371.2px;

```
<section id="home" class="home-section home-parallax home-fade bg-dark-30" data-background="" style="background-position: 20px 8px, 11px 6px, 5px 3px;">
```